# MySQL is not starting in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Now I'm working with some projects so I fill my Database using xampp(my english is s*cking, sorry). I get error:

```
Warning: Unknown(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

I changed session storage and  get next level of headache:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory — Server isn't responding (or local socket of Mysql incorrectly configured ).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
An error occurred while indicating the connection for controluser in configuration
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.
```

Previously I installed conkeror browser and tried to set it as default browser. After some time (about 4hrs) mysql crashed. I used commmands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser 
sudo update-desktop-database
```

I really need to save my database because it contains so mush data...
Please help (
About my computer: Debian 8 GNOME + Awesome WM. Lenovo b590.

Comment: Your hard drive or partition is full. This is not a programming question but more of a general OS one.

Comment: No, I changed session directory I said, this problem solved I think. I have many free space on the disk, but opt directory small.

Comment: The error is very specific, so if you fixed it, great, but it was a space problem.

Comment: I solved a problem with space for session files, but problem with mysql working is still here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution. I watched my logs and mysql couldn't init tc.log (/opt/lampp/var/mysql/tc.log).
I just removed it and started the server. It started working!

But I still must move my logs to the other partition, because logs eat so much memory...